# make xml drill down

Tags: xml, xslt

We have an xml doc that contains different levels:

```
<Root>
    <folder name="aaa">
        <folder name="abb">
            <file name="ccc.pdf" url="c:\test\ccc.pdf"/>
            <file name="ddd.pdf" url="c:\test\ddd.pdf"/>
            <file name="eee.pdf" url="c:\test\eee.pdf"/>
            <file name="fff.pdf" url="c:\test\fff.pdf"/>
        </folder>
        <folder name="acc">
            <file name="ggg.pdf" url="c:\test\ggg.pdf"/>
            <file name="hhh.pdf" url="c:\test\hhh.pdf"/>
        </folder>
    </folder>
    <folder name="bbb">
        <folder name="bba">
            <file name="iii.pdf" url="c:\test\iii.pdf"/>
        </folder>
        <folder name="bbc" />
    </folder>
    <folder name="ccc">
            <file name="iii.pdf" url="c:\test\iii.pdf"/>
            <file name="jjj.pdf" url="c:\test\jjj.pdf"/>
            <file name="kkk.pdf" url="c:\test\kkk.pdf"/>
            <file name="lll.pdf" url="c:\test\lll.pdf"/>
    </folder>
</Root>
```

My question is how to using xsl to make the xml drill down like expand collapse(toggle) the folder name. and also make the file linkable (by the attribute url)

Comment: Can you clarify what "drill down" means? Is it just indentation? A collapsible/expandable tree? Maybe if you post what you've tried, it will be easier to see what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I need expand expand collapse(toggle) the folder name and make the file name as a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you plan on implementing your tree is going to determine how you need your output structured.

Here's an example using [jQuery treeView](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/treeview/index.htm).

**XML Input**

```
<Root>
    <folder name="aaa">
        <folder name="abb">
            <file name="ccc.pdf" url="c:\test\ccc.pdf"/>
            <file name="ddd.pdf" url="c:\test\ddd.pdf"/>
            <file name="eee.pdf" url="c:\test\eee.pdf"/>
            <file name="fff.pdf" url="c:\test\fff.pdf"/>
        </folder>
        <folder name="acc">
            <file name="ggg.pdf" url="c:\test\ggg.pdf"/>
            <file name="hhh.pdf" url="c:\test\hhh.pdf"/>
        </folder>
    </folder>
    <folder name="bbb">
        <folder name="bba">
            <file name="iii.pdf" url="c:\test\iii.pdf"/>
        </folder>
        <folder name="bbc" />
    </folder>
    <folder name="ccc">
        <file name="iii.pdf" url="c:\test\iii.pdf"/>
        <file name="jjj.pdf" url="c:\test\jjj.pdf"/>
        <file name="kkk.pdf" url="c:\test\kkk.pdf"/>
        <file name="lll.pdf" url="c:\test\lll.pdf"/>
    </folder>
</Root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
                <title>StackOverflow Test of jQuery treeView</title>

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery.treeview.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="../red-treeview.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" />

                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="../lib/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script src="../jquery.treeview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function() {
                    $("#browser").treeview();
                    });
                </script>

            </head>
            <body>
                <ul id="browser" class="filetree">                  
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </ul>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="folder">
        <li>
            <span class="folder"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></span>
            <xsl:if test="folder">
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="folder"/>
                </ul>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="file">
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="file"/>
                </ul>
            </xsl:if>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="file">
        <li>
            <span class="file">
                <a href="file:///{translate(@url,'/','\')}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                </a>                
            </span>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>StackOverflow Test of jQuery treeView</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery.treeview.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../red-treeview.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="../lib/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="../jquery.treeview.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function() {
                    $("#browser").treeview();
                    });
                </script></head>
   <body>
      <ul id="browser" class="filetree">
         <li><span class="folder">aaa</span><ul>
               <li><span class="folder">abb</span><ul>
                     <li><span class="file"><a href="file:///c:\test\ccc.pdf">ccc.pdf</a></span></li>
                     <li><span class="file"><a href="file:///c:\test\ddd.pdf">ddd.pdf</a></span></li>
                     <li><span class="file"><a href="file:///c:\test\eee.pdf">eee.pdf</a></span></li>
                     <li><span class="file"><a href="file:///c:\test\fff.pdf">fff.pdf</a></span></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li><span class="folder">acc</span><ul>
                     <li><span class="file"><a href="file:///c:\test\ggg.pdf">ggg.pdf</a></span></li>
                     <li><span class="file"><a href="file:///c:\test\hhh.pdf">hhh.pdf</a></span></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><span class="folder">bbb</span><ul>
               <li><span class="folder">bba</span><ul>
                     <li><span class="file"><a href="file:///c:\test\iii.pdf">iii.pdf</a></span></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li><span class="folder">bbc</span></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><span class="folder">ccc</span><ul>
               <li><span class="file"><a href="file:///c:\test\iii.pdf">iii.pdf</a></span></li>
               <li><span class="file"><a href="file:///c:\test\jjj.pdf">jjj.pdf</a></span></li>
               <li><span class="file"><a href="file:///c:\test\kkk.pdf">kkk.pdf</a></span></li>
               <li><span class="file"><a href="file:///c:\test\lll.pdf">lll.pdf</a></span></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

**HTML Output Rendered**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. That's very helpful. But why those link I can't open on that page. But if I copy the url paste to another tab is okay?

Comment: @MikeLong - I'm not sure; it works fine for me in Firefox and IE 8. I don't have any experience with treeView though (prior to today).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ? This will scan all elements, find the elements named "file" and replace them with a clickable link. In fact, it will only produce a list of clickable links. All the folder informations will not be visible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Clickable file URIs</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//file" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="file">
        <a href="{@url}"><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></a><br />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```